# What is the convergence radius of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ when $\{a_{n}\}$ is s.t. $a_1 = 1, a_{n+1} = \sin(a_{n})$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My task is this:

Given a sequence $\{a_n\}$ with $a_1 = 1, a_{n+1} = \sin(a_{n}).$

(i) Show that the sequence converge and find the limit as $n\to\infty$.

(ii) Show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ converge for $|x|<1$.

(iii) Show that the series converge for $x=-1$ and diverges for $x=1$.

My work so far:

(i) $\forall \ a \in I =\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\ $we have that $a > \sin(a)$. We see that $a_1 \in I \implies a_{n+1}<a_{n}$, and it should be known that $\sin(I) \geq 0$. My claim is therefore that $a_n\to 0$. For any $\epsilon > 0$ we must show that $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}:|a_n - 0| = |a_n| = a_n<\epsilon$ when $n\geq N$.  Choose $N:\sin(a_N)<1/N<\epsilon$, such a number exists by archemedian property. We have now shown that the $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n = 0$. This is a strictly monotonically decreasing sequence which is bounded and therefore convergent.

(ii) $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{a_nx^n}\right| = |x|<1$.

(iii) It should be pretty clear that for $x=-1$ we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n| =0 \implies$ convergence. There is a theorem for this.

P.s. There is a hint that states $\sin(1/n)>1/n - 1/6n^3$ if that is of any help. I couldn't figure it out, but would be very glad if someone could!

Comment: Hint on that hint: what is the difference between $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}$?  What does it imply that this difference is larger than $\frac{1}{6n^3}$?

Comment: Also, your (i) is wrong: the fact that $a_{n+1} \lt a_n$ for all $n$ implies that the sequence _converges_, but not necessarily that it converges to $0$.  You need to do more to prove that.

Comment: To show divergence at $x=1$, it is enough to show that $a_n$ is "big", say bigger than \frac{1}{4n}$. This can be done by induction,  using the bound of the hint.

Comment: @ Steven Stadnicki Thanks, I've added some changes now, hope they are sufficient as I am still new to proving things in general!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that $\sin(a_n)\geq \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{6n^3}$. For $n=1$, this is true from the hint. Suppose that this is valid for $n$, then $a_{n+1}=\sin(a_{n})\geq\sin(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{6n^3})$, Now $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{6n^3}-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{6n^2-n-1}{6n^3(n+1)}$. Since $6n^2-n-1\geq 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, it follows that $a_{n+1}\geq\sin(\frac{1}{n+1})\geq\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{6(n+1)^3}$. Then $\sum a_n\geq\sum\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{6n^3}=\infty$.